# Free OCR for youtube and screen

Tags: windows, gratis, ocr

I'm looking for a downloadable freeware (gratis) that works similarly to  `Windows Snipping Tool`. You create a rectangle around the required text and the software transforms it into regular text. If it keeps the alignment it would be better. The software should work for both screens and video.
The OS is Windows 7 and on. The software should be freeware.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use **[Capture2Text](https://sourceforge.net/projects/capture2text/)**.

[image]

- Free.
- For Windows.
- The way it works is by drawing a rectangle on the screen.
- It can treat the image of videos too (I tested it playing a video with subtitles in **[SMPlayer](http://www.smplayer.eu/)**).
- Good OCR results for English and Spanish language, at least.

Personally is one of my favorite apps of this kind.

---

UPDATE:

If useful, these are the settings that I'm using:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. I already downloaded it. However, I have some difficulties to use it. Can you instruct me how to use it?

Comment: @Avi When you initialise the app, a icon will appear in the system tray, click on it and select "Preferences" to assign the hotkey to draw the rectangle, just as an example in my case i have assigned "**#q**" (Windows key + Q), in the OCR tab you can configure the OCR dictionary language, and, in the "Output" tab you can specify whether to send the OCR results to clipboard, if you uncheck that option, the OCR results will be stored in the file "ocr.txt" located the installation folder of the application.

Comment: I have some difficulties to work with it. When I press "#q" (Windows key + Q) sometimes I see the rectangle sometimes not. When I tried to open your logo and scan it the software didn't allow me. Do I have to locate the mouse pointer besides the scanned element, prees #q and drag the rectangle by mouse?

Comment: @Avi Have you been through [this](http://capture2text.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: Thanks Jan, I have already seen it. Sometimes I succeed in capturing the zone to be OCR and sometimes not. Maybe I do something wrong...

Comment: @ElektroStudios, Thanks again. How can I add the speech recognition as well. (In my installation it doesn't exist) the rest of the preferences parameters are equal except for some additional fields you have and I don't

Comment: @Avi They removed it (the images I shared are from version 3.5), see what they says in the version history: https://sourceforge.net/projects/capture2text/files/Dictionaries/ Version 3.6 (5-15-2015)] - Removed the experimental speech recognition feature due to new Google Speech API v2 quota restrictions.

Comment: Maybe you can help me with running the software. When I press #q should I hold it and drag the mouse for choosing the text? Or should I point with the mouse near the required area, then press #q, release and then left click and drag the mouse for choosing the required OCR area?

Comment: When you press (not hold) **#q** the rectangle is activated under your mouse position, then you move the mouse to increase the rectangle's size to select the desired area, and finally press left-button click to release the rectangle and perform the OCR.